# Git не делает push на сервер

Tags: git, git-commit, gitlab, git-push

Есть убунта, установил gitlab, создал тестовый проект.
add an SSH key - не сделал, т.к. винда на которой предполагается разработка, выдает мне ошибку при создании ключа (no such file or...)
На винду поставил source tree, склонировал этот тестовый репозиторий, добавил новый файл, делаю коммит, при отправке на сервер получаю:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F C:\Users\sanu0074\AppData\Local\Temp\v4o3fdrf.f5l
XPath error : Invalid expression
/userSettings/victims/*[exact_name='git.exe']/(null)[1]/*[1]
                                              ^
XPath error : Invalid expression
/userSettings/victims/*[exact_name='git.exe']/(null)[1]/*[1]
                                              ^
XPath error : Invalid expression
/userSettings/victims/*[exact_name='sourcetree.exe']/(null)[1]/*[1]
                                                     ^
XPath error : Invalid expression
/userSettings/victims/*[exact_name='sourcetree.exe']/(null)[1]/*[1]
                                                     ^
XPath error : Invalid expression
/userSettings/default/(null)[1]/*[1]
                      ^
XPath error : Invalid expression
/userSettings/default/(null)[1]/*[1]
                      ^
```

Почему это происходит? Я совсем плохо разбираюсь как в гитлабе, так и в самом гите, хочу научиться, так как это очень удобно, и хочется забыть про фтп. Очень благодарен за внимание!

Comment: в git commit не отправляет на сервер. Поэтому, текст вопроса звучит немного кривовато. Я уже много раз писал - source tree лучше сразу выбросить. Если git не знаете, он будет мешать. Если знаете, то будете пользоваться консолью. 

судя по тексту ошибки - похоже sourcetree что то чудит. А понимать, что там начудили - нет смысла.

Поэтому поставьте нормальный [гит](https://git-scm.com/download/win) и все таки настройте его (сам гитлаб имеет хорошие инструкции, как добавить ключ).

Есть ещё один способ - поставьте клиент от гихаба. Достаточно хорош был (когда я им когда то пользовался).

Comment: а просто любая команда в консоли, например, ping 8.8.8.8, у вас не выдает такую же ошибку?

Comment: @KoVadim, SourceTree - великолепный интсрумент. Не нужно стращать автора вопроса. Если он Вам чем-то не угодил, то это ничего не значит.

Comment: @sanu0074, попробуйте для начала создать репозиторий на каком-нибудь gitgub, разобраться, что всё работает. А потом уже настраивать свой сервер. Да и в целом, Вы уверены, что Вам нужен свой сервер? bitbucket, к примеру, предлагает неограниченное количество приватных репозиториев совершенно бесплатно

Comment: @PashaPash выдает даже простая команда

Answer (score 2):

> XPath error : Invalid expression
>   /userSettings/victims/*[exact_name='git.exe']/(null)[1]/*[1]

это не ошибка git и не ошибка source tree. скорее всего что-то вписалось у вас стандартным обработчиком команд, и это что-то не может прочитать свои настройки.

Проверить можно запустив cmd.exe и выполнив там что-то стандартное, например ping. Если будут такие же ошибки - значит git тут ни при чем.

В cmd можно влезть несколькими способами, например, через extensions. Если в обычном cmd будут ошибки - запустите `cmd /d /e:off` и попробуйте выполнить команду в нем. Если и там будут ошибки - берите system monitor и ищите что у вас запускается при каждой команде.

Судя по гуглу - это может быть Adobe Air. Но может и просто какой-то зловред.

К сожалению, и sourcetree и git extensions полагаются на точный консольный вывод от git.exe, и ваши ошибки скорее всего ломают GUI.

Comment: как же выявить, что именно есть причиной этой ошибки?

Comment: @sanu0074 я же написал - если в `cmd /d /e:off` работает нормально - то это экстеншены к cmd. Если ненормально - берите Sysmon и ищите что происходит прямо перез выполнением вызванного приложения.

Comment: в cmd /d /e:off - то же самое

Comment: Установил sysmon, но не пойму как пользоваться?

Comment: Утилита работает:                       ^
Sysmon installed.
SysmonDrv installed.
Starting SysmonDrv.
SysmonDrv started.
Starting Sysmon.
Но ошибки вываливаются как и раньше, и где что смотреть?